# Scala implicit conversion scope issues

Tags: scala, implicit, implicit-conversion

Take this code:

```
  class Register(var value:Int = 0) {
      def getZeroFlag() : Boolean = (value & 0x80) != 0
  }

  object Register {
      implicit def reg2int(r:Register):Int = r.value
      implicit def bool2int(b:Boolean):Int = if (b) 1 else 0
  }
```

I want to use it like so:

```
val x = register.getZeroFlag + 10
```

but I am greeted with:

```
type mismatch; found : Boolean required: Int
```

What goes? Do I need to define a implicit taking a function that returns a bool?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an example demonstrating how to use your implicits:

```
object Test {
  val register = new Register(42)
  val x = 1 + register // implicitly calling reg2int from companion object
  val y = register - 1 // same
  // val z = register + 1 // doesn't work because "+" means string concatenation

  // need to bring bool2int implicit into scope before it can be used
  import Register._
  val w = register.getZeroFlag() + 2 // this works now
  val z2 = register + 1 // works because in-scope implicits have higher priority 
}
```

Two potentially non-obvious things here:

- When seeking implicit conversions to or from an object of type `Register`, the compiler will look in the companion object `Register`. This is why we didn't need to bring `reg2int` explicitly into scope for defining `x` and `y`. However, the conversion `bool2int` does need to be in scope because it's not defined on the `Boolean` or `Int` companion object.
- The method `+` is already defined on all objects to mean string concatenation via the implicit `any2stringadd` in `scala.Predef`. The definition `val z` is illegal because the implicit for string concatenation takes priority over `reg2int` (implicits found in companion objects are relatively low priority). However, the definition `val z2` works because we've brought `reg2int` into scope, giving it higher priority.

For more details about how the compiler searches for implicits, see Daniel Sobral's very nice explanation: [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Comment: Fantastic. That explains the scoping really well.

Comment: I just figured out that the ._ on the Object is necessary to import the things defined in the Object. Thought this would be "implicit" (pun intended)