# Add two tuples containing simple elements in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

Is there a easy way to add tuples which contain addable elements like Int, Doubles etc?
For examples,

```
(1,2) + (1,3) = (2,5)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? mostly using tuples for such thing (might be) considered bad style.

Comment: tuples aren't intended for this type of thing. They're just a convenient wrapper for methods that return multiple values, which is why they don't have a host of useful functions like collections do.

Comment: I was trying to reduce a list of tuples. I am using tuples to do some map reduce type operations. Customs classes and objects seems overkill.

Comment: @Arun, if you are working with lists of tuples you might find (my) project https://github.com/marklister/product-collections useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

scala> (1, 2.5) |+| (3, 4.4)
res0: (Int, Double) = (4,6.9)
```

There is an operator `|+|` for any class `A` with implicit `Semigroup[A]` in scope. For `Int` `|+|` is `+` by default (you could redefine it in your code).

There is an implicit `Semigroup[(A, B)]` for all tuples if there is implicit `Semigroup` for `A` and `B`.

See [Scalaz cheat sheet](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet).

Answer (score 13):

+1 for the the [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) answer :-)

If you want a very simple version of it you could define an implicit class like:

```
implicit class TuppleAdd(t: (Int, Int)) {
  def +(p: (Int, Int)) = (p._1 + t._1, p._2 + t._2)
}

(1, 1) + (2, 2) == (3, 3)
```

// update1, more generic version for numbers:

So this is the simplest version, defined only for `Int`s, we could generify it for all numeric values using Scala's `Numeric`:

```
implicit class Tupple2Add[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](t: (A, B)) {
  import Numeric.Implicits._

  def + (p: (A, B)) = (p._1 + t._1, p._2 + t._2)
}

(2.0, 1) + (1.0, 2) == (3.0, 3)
```

Comment: There is not only `Int` in the question. You could improve your answer with `math.Numeric` like this: `implicit class TuppleAdd[A : Numeric, B : Numeric](t: (A, B)) {  import Numeric.Implicits._;  def +(p: (A, B)) = (p._1 + t._1, p._2 + t._2) }`.

Comment: That is true :-) I also thought about a version with a structural type, but let's not go there maybe ;-)

Comment: I've also tried to implement `implicit def tupleIsNumeric[A : Numeric, B : Numeric]: Numeric[(A, B)]`, but there is [an issue](http://pastebin.com/fyty7mMy) with `+` operator (`-` and `*` works fine).

Comment: Does your `+` issue perchance have to do with this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906742/scala-implicit-conversion-scope-issues

Answer (score 1):

This works with [`Cats`](https://typelevel.org/cats/) as well, and similar to the `scalaz` answer:

```scala
> (1,2) |+| (1,3)
res3: (Int, Int) = (2, 5)
```

And likewise, it relies on [`Semigroup`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html).